# Отправить запрос через прокси golang

Tags: golang, proxy

Столкнулся с проблемой. Имеется файл со списком проксей в виде ip:port
Вопрос в том как сделать отправку запроса через эти прокси(как читать файл и сплитить я знаю, но не могу найти информацию как сделать запрос через прокси из моего файла). Интересуют способы запроса через все типы проксей(http(s), socks4 и socks5), если это возможно, но, а так хотя бы с http(s)

Comment: Для начала почитайте про [`net/http.Transport.Proxy`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport.Proxy).

Answer (score 1):

Для HTTP(S), как было замечено @Aniar-G, используйте [http.Transport.Proxy](https://godoc.org/net/http#Transport.Proxy):

```
client := &http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        Proxy: selectProxyFromList,
    },
}
resp, err := client.Get("https://example.com")
// stuff
```

Для Socks5 используйте пакет [golang.org/x/net/proxy](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/proxy) и его функцию [SOCKS5](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/proxy#SOCKS5).

```
dialer, err := proxy.SOCKS5("tcp", "127.0.0.1:9050", nil, proxy.Direct)
if err != nil {
    // handle err
}
client := &http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        Dial: dialer.Dial,
    },
}
resp, err := client.Get("https://example.com")
// stuff
```

Так же возможно (никогда не пользовался), подойдёт пакет [h12.io/socks](https://godoc.org/h12.io/socks) для SOCKS4, SOCKS4A и SOCKS5. Он идёт с хорошим примером использования. Этот пакет не поддерживает аутентификацию.